# OAuth2 variable redirect_uri

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

We're writing a plugin that integrates with an OAuth2 api.

The tricky part is that we can't hard code the redirect URI like in in most integrations, because clients could install this plugin on any domain they control (think Wordpress plugin), and the access token needs to redirect back to their custom url.

We saw you can set a `state` parameter also in OAuth2.  So we could hard code the redirect URI as `http://oursite.com/callback` and set a state of `https://[CUSTOM_URL]`.

Then `http://oursite.com/callback` would do an additional redirect to the custom URL, passing along the access tokens.

However, this seems like a security vulnerability, because once a user had authenticated the app, someone else could come along and cause it to reauthenticate with their own url in the `state` param.  Then it would happily redirect to their bad url and pass them the access token.

So how do people set up OAuth2 integrations where the redirect_uri can vary?  Thanks!

P.S. One solution we thought of was to *only* allow the `state` param to be used if the redirect uri was a url that we control.  Then we can create another verification page which prompts the user again: "Do you want to allow https://customurl.com to access your account...".  But we thought there might be a better way.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I was asking me the same questions, how to do you implement Oauth 2.0 authentication for Wordpress Plugins, where the redirect URL can vary depending on where it is installed

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic client addresses it may worth considering the use of localhost-based redirect URIs. This may sound counterintuitive first, but since OAuth2 is a browser/httpclientlib-based protocol, it works. The redirection from the authorization endpoint of the server is done by your own browser, so localhost as redirect_uri is always properly resolved. As a result you can still have a fix redirect_uri wherever you deploy your application.

This solution also has its implications, you should consider architectural and security consequences. The localhost-based redirect_uri nicely fits the implicit grant scenario (i.e. javascript client) well, but I think that for the authorization code grant scenario (i.e. remote web application) you should use a remotely accessible hostname instead.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I don't think I'm understanding.  How would setting the redirect_uri to localhost help, and what would happen if it tried to redirect to localhost - presumably they don't have a web server running locally, so I must be missing something.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Localhost can work as a unified redirect_uri for all clients deployed to different servers, without the need to add a separate URI to the state. To properly resolve localhost, the browser must be on the same machine as the client application, so this works with the implicit flow (i.e. javascript clients, e.g. applications on your phone). For javascript clients, you don't need a local webserver, you only have to detect the redirect and extract the token from the redirect URI.

Comment: I'm also trying to find an alternative like BrianArmstrong but when you enter the localhost to redirect_uri from application management user will be redirected to localhost and your javascript or server side code will not reach that access_token anyway. May be client side login is available for facebook because they already have javascript sdk but many oauth providers don't. Is there something that i'm missing @Zólyomi István ?

Comment: This was a long time ago and we used a custom OAuth2 server. Frankly I have no idea how Facebook currently does it. :-/

Answer (score 0):

To me, you are in the right direction and IMHO that's the only approach to pass the information with the state. 
To not have security concerns I would suggest you not pass the URL in the state, but pass the keyword. And then have a mapping in your app which handles the `http://oursite.com/callback` URL, and only when the keyword exists in your mapping you can redirect to the corresponding URL from that mapping.