# What should be the base URL of the "redirect_uri"?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, popup, greasemonkey

Even after working with OAuth2 for 3+ months while writing a now-working GreaseMonkey userscript, I am still profoundly confused regarding what I should be using for the seemingly arbitrary parameter `redirect_uri` when performing implicit grant flow authorization. Nearly all the OAuth2 instructions describe the redirect_uri as "[redirecting back to your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602380/redirect-back-to-application-from-redirect-uri-page)" or being set to [http://localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626054/oauth2-variable-redirect-uri).

My GreaseMonkey script makes a button on a website (let's refer to that website as `https://www.site1.com/xxxxxx`) -- site1.com is similar to google.com and the xxxxx is like a personal Google Doc file number.  Given this situation, exactly what does it mean to "redirect back to my application"? My application doesn't have a link to send someone back to.  Do these words actually mean to redirect back to the page on which my application is executing (e.g., to `https://www.site1.com`)?  Or do the words mean to to redirect back to the different website that was providing authorization (let's refer to that website as `https://www.site2.com` ... which could be, for example, DropBox). Or should I instead be defining `redirect_uri` such that it points to some html page that I created? (And if so, should that html file be placed on `https://www.site1.com`, or at `https://www.site2.com`, or on a local hard drive of my computer, or does it matter? The other option, `http://localhost`,  gives me a "page not found" error, so that was a no-go as I was unable to even extract the hash fragment to get the token.

To summarize: **Should the `redirect_uri` have `https://www.site1.com` or `https://www.site2.com` or something entirely different, such as a personally-made html file that one somehow makes the userscript land on after redirect?**  If I can just get this one missing piece of the puzzle solved (e.g, swap out my rather arbitrary choice of `redirect_uri` for something that makes sense and is consistent with what other others do), then my already-working code will be finalized. The one remaining open task for my userscript development is figuring out how to close the redirected post-authorization popup window. I have a suspicion that my inability to close that popup has something to do with the choice of base URL in the `redirect_uri` that I haven't gotten quite right yet!